# ASP.NET application to host on Java EE configured directory

Tags: asp.net, jakarta-ee, publishing

One of our clients has a Java EE application. We would like to develop a new project using ASP.NET/C# by hosting the application as a sub directory under this Java EE project.

My questions are:

1. Will the .NET application run smoothly?
2. Do I need to keep anything in mind before I make a promise to the client?

Answer (score 0):

The way you strucure your projects do not affect the behavior of your applications at all.
However in the end, each of the compiled and not compiled resources need to be configured propoerly to their proper Web Server, you shouldn't have any problem at all.
IIS has its own directory and Tomcat(or whatever you are using) will have its own directory.
Just let him understand that there is no sense on sharing the projects in a single root folder if the projects are not going to be related at all.

The only way to make them interact is by means of services and queues that you can orchestrate in any of both technologies.

***UPDATE***

let's suppose that:

you are using default of both web servers: your IIS need your applications to be copied to c:\inetpub folder whereas tomcat uses the $CATALINA_BASE system variable to locate their own folder. That won't be a problem at all.

Now, let's suppose that your client chose the same exact folder to be the root of your websites in tomcat and iis, (very bad maintenance decision by the way)
you could also separate both environments by having two folders : JAVA and DOTNET

Now let's suppose your client won't accept any logic suggestion, and you have to merge java files and aspx files, technically there won't be any issue because each web server will handle requests for very different issues, however, if you are also using the same resources, let's say a picture used in both pages, you will have locked-files issues, your iis can only respond for its own behavior and tomcat will only respond with its own behavior.

So in summary, technically speaking it could work, performance will be hit on your hard drive, it all depends on the request loads of each app, but overall it is a bad infrastructure design.

hope it helps,

Comment: Jorge, Thanks for your reply. Client is having his existing system on root folder, and we have to put the new app on the same server which is in result to put physical directory under root. this new directory having asp.net code while root having java code.